Bootstrap 5 Modal at input form accept only value "A, B, C or 0"
Triggered Input to perform Modal
<input class="btn btn-outline-dark w-100" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#updateEkskulModal" data-bs-cdcod="cdcod" data-bs-cdpts="cdpts" data-bs-cduid="cduid" data-bs-cdref="cdref" data-bs-cdsmt="cdsmt" type="button" value="cdpts"`>

Modal
<div class="modal-body">
<input class="form-control" maxlength="1" id="ekskulpts" name="ekskulpts" required style="text-transform:uppercase">
</div>

JS
<script>
    const cdptsModal = document.getElementById('updateEkskulModal')
    if (cdptsModal) {
      cdptsModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', event => {
        const button = event.relatedTarget
        const cdcod = button.getAttribute('data-bs-cdcod')
        const cduid = button.getAttribute('data-bs-cduid')
        const cdsub = button.getAttribute('data-bs-cdsub')
        const cdpts = button.getAttribute('data-bs-cdpts')
        const cdsmt = button.getAttribute('data-bs-cdsmt')
        $("#ekskulcod").val(cdcod);
        $("#ekskuluid").val(cduid);
        $("#ekskulsub").val(cdsub);
        $("#ekskulpts").val(cdpts);
        $("#ekskulsmt").val(cdsmt);
      })
    }
</script>

Bootstrap 5 input-form accept only value "A, B, C or 0" since JQuery is no longer used in BS 5 (Modal)

To set value of element using vanilla js you can use document.querySelector("#ekskulcod").value = cdcod
